# How to find corresponding snapshot file in VMware?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, snapshot

I am using ESXi 4.1. I am a having VM with 3 snapshots.

When exploring datastore , snapshot vmdk name doesn't contain any word from snapshot name.

How to find snapshot vmdk for corresponding snapshot?

```
For ex. "ie88nt8ksvm081-000004.vmdk"
```

Does the above vmdk means it is the 4th snapshot in hierarchy?

Answer (score 3):

The snapshot names are related to the virtual disk file they are based on, which need not be related to the name of the virtual machine, and quite unlikely to have anything to do with any labels given to the snapshot.

The numbers after the disk file name are primarily a unique ID to ensure that the filename is unique.  From my observation this does often indicate the order of the snapshot file, where snapshots have not been used frequently for that VM.  However, there is no guarantee of this, and where lots of snapshots have been created then deleted, you may see something different.

VMware have [a good document discussing snapshots which covers the naming convention](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1015180).

Note there are additional files relating to snapshots, also detailed in the document linked above.